# CompilationFailedException when using IRazorViewEngine in non Sdk.Web projects to render Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, razorgenerator

I am trying to use `IRazorViewEngine` in a console application `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` (not `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`) to render a `.cshtml` page in memory. I registered every needed dependency in the `ServiceProvider`. While calling the following line I get a `CompilationFailedException`:

```cs
_viewEngine.GetView(directory, name, true);
```

Exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
>       kmcajniq.bah(4,20): error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>       kmcajniq.bah(5,19): error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>       kmcajniq.bah(4,82): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported
>       kmcajniq.bah(4,115): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
>       kmcajniq.bah(4,132): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
>       kmcajniq.bah(5,81): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported

and other more missing `System` and `Microsoft` types.

**However**, when I'm changing the project sdk to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` everything works fine.

What is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` missing what `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` does, that Razor rendering works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the `RazorViewEngine` needs the compilation context to compile the Razor pages during run time. The default setting for this is in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` set to false, while it is set in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` to `true`.

To fix the problem the following property needs to be added to the `.csproj` file and set to `true`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Additional info about differences can be found here [What are the differences between Microsoft.NET.Sdk and Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434690/what-are-the-differences-between-microsoft-net-sdk-and-microsoft-net-sdk-web)